# PDO Union Count

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
public function totalRecords($keyword) {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM user_information WHERE title LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR surname LIKE ? 
          UNION ALL
          SELECT COUNT(id) FROM groups WHERE name LIKE ?";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array("%$keyword%", "%$keyword%", "%$keyword%", "%$keyword%"));
    return $query->rowCount();
}
```

I am trying to create pager, and i need to total records of search term.

Above code does not work, it always return 0. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)**

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the
>   last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding
>   PDOStatement object.

So you have to use `fetch()` with `sum()`

```
public function totalRecords($keyword) {
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(num) as num  FROM
             (SELECT COUNT(uid) as num FROM user_information WHERE title LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR surname LIKE ? 
             UNION ALL
            SELECT COUNT(id)as num FROM groups WHERE name LIKE ?)
            AS X";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array("%$keyword%", "%$keyword%", "%$keyword%", "%$keyword%"));
    $Total = $query->fetch();
   return $Total['num'];
}
```

Comment: But this query will return _two_ records. Currently your code snippet returns only the `COUNT(uid) as num FROM user_information` part.

Comment: yes you are correct it will return two record. Thanks for pointing this. I updated my answer

Comment: Now it's working. I delete my answer; there's no need for alternatives here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on [`rowCount`](https://devdocs.io/php/pdostatement.rowcount):

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated `PDOStatement`
>   was a `SELECT` statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

Since you are using a `UNION ALL` without ny `GROUP BY`s in sub-queries, the fetched results would be 2 rows. One showing the count from `user_information` table and another for the `groups` table. You probably want to use `->fetch()` statement here.

Also, since all the placeholders in your query are for the same values, use a named placeholder:

```
public function totalRecords($keyword) {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(uid)
        FROM user_information
        WHERE title LIKE :kwd
            OR name LIKE :kwd
            OR surname LIKE :kwd 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT COUNT(id)
        FROM groups
        WHERE name LIKE :kwd";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute( array(":kwd" => "%$keyword%") );
    // the resulting array needs to be processed accordingly
    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```